# TypeScript infer arguments of methods defined on an object

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-inference

Let's say I have `methods` defined like this:

```
const methods = {
    methodOne(a: string) { return a; },

    methodTwo(a: number) { return a; },

    methodThree() {}
} as const;
```

I can infer type of `methods`:

```
type MethodDefinitions = typeof methods;
```

Now let's say that I want to create a function that can execute any method on `methods` like so:

```
function doStuff<T extends keyof MethodDefinitions>(t: T, arg: Parameters<MethodDefinitions[T]>[0]) {
    const method = methods[t];
    method(arg);
}
```

Here, I would expect `method` to have a specific type inferred from `T` and `methods`. However, TS playground says that the type of `method` is `(a: never) => string | number | void`, and complains when I try to call `method` with `arg`.

How can I fix that without resolving to `any` cast? One solution that I found is casting `arg` to `never` (`method(arg as never)`), but that doesn't seem ideal.

Here's a link to TS playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAEwjAvDA3gKBiPiVTQHkwEAKAQwC4ZoAnASzAHMBKPGZpAK7MwMWgG4YAXwA0+QsUQp0AFQDuIOozAC4AIwTMeuPoOGiJMucRJK0y5PxpHJ+SaMyhIUMXKgBPAAcEGABZUnQAEQQAM3ZWKFZwTBx-IJBomzIIH3xogTBgBPAYNBAAZSgBaOiAHmUYBAAPKAQwDBgAawQ-dNDwtCjYsHjEyAA+aihGZWlRZg5GAAVaZlpFAwgasNtBuKLIAG1lAF0xg4AGY6N5Ik9oTPRsB4wDqGOfa0UyOnmuHxcgA).

Answer (score 0):

We have two issues:

First, the args is an array of arguments. You cannot pass it like that when calling a function. You have a few options:

```js
   method.apply(null, args);
   //OR
    method(...args);
```

Second, typescript is not perfect, and although your code seems to protect the input - typescript is not aware of that. So you can enforce it by casting to any. The previous becomes:

```js
    (method as any).apply(null, args);
    (method as any)(...args);
```

Then the whole function will look like this:

```js
function doStuff<T extends keyof MethodDefinitions>(t: T, ...args: Parameters<MethodDefinitions[T]>) {
    const method = methods[t];
    (method as any).apply(null, args);
    //(method as any)(...args); - or this approach if you like it
}
```

Working example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAEwjAvDA3gKBiPiVTQHkwEAKAQwC4ZoAnASzAHMBKPGUSEABsEAOkEgO1AAaIU6Sgj61BwtDADurFDAAkuWgF8pXANzMkAV2ZgYtEzAMAafIWKyyAFXUg6jMBbgAIwRmHlw%20cAghUXFJGVJ0LxAlFQQ1TW09Q2N7cygrGzsHZ1cid0TkcxowiIFhMQlpcrQPSoRFYGVVHOKXYhI5NAAxECtqMFpERhZ2DkdbDgQ-AODQ3n4o%20timhOHR5hTVDS1kGAmp3VxzhANbMDVaRcYsxaNTB3xb2kwNqBMXKAATwADooALK7AAiCAAZuwtKxItgYEDQSAYQMyBB-vgYRYwMAoIibGgQABlfIwmEAHg8MAQAA8oAh7pgANYIQHomAQwbQuFgBGRAB81CgjA88xE0tozA4EEYAAVZZMkCEINTeWR%20fCiZEANoeAC6wrCpVq0Ex6GRzQg%20qgRv%20-QA9M7qM1bJhaGBAVwRLRgcDBIDxhYVPNZfLTOb3btPXdfdRpf65RBowYXPhSRSLFTqAAiZoKfPzfMAKxAyDA%20ej2cpMILzSSJZgADZa%20T643dq0qjX-nXcw3C7sRlYW-nFWrmC2AOzt-5AA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my example I defined `args` as `Parameters<MethodDefinitions[T]>[0]`. Note the `0` in the end; `args` is actually an `arg`, so I've updated my question to reflect that.

I would also prefer not to use "any" cast, since I do use the [no-explicit-any](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/) ESLint rule.